# Delay and animate toggle jquery

Tags: toggle, jquery

I am trying to play arround and I am totally newbie with jquery! So I need some help definetly :)

```
$(function() {
        $('#switch').on('click', function() {
            $('#customOverlay').toggle();
        });
    });
```

I made an light switcher and I am trying to turn the light on/off by adding customOverlay.

It works really fine but not as expected. I want to delay it for like 1000ms and I want to animate it cause this way it just turn the visibility on and off really quick. Is this possible cause I cannot even delay it and I dont know how would I animate toggle.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try [.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) :

```
$(function() {
        $('#switch').on('click', function() {
            $('#customOverlay').delay(1000).fadeToggle();
        });
});
```

OR

```
$(function() {
        $('#switch').on('click', function() {
            $('#customOverlay').fadeToggle(1000);
        });
});
```

The other answers that only use `.delay()` and `.toggle` won't work because `.delay()` only applies to the animation queue and `.toggle()` doesn't animate, while `.fadeToggle()` does.

Comment: Woah... This works pretty perfectly. Thanks for quick answer. Havent seen .fadeToggle yet. I am sorry :]

Comment: No need to be sorry, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.delay()`

```
$('#customOverlay').delay(1000).fadeToggle();
```